# Unreachable Code Detected (Why?)

Tags: c#, unreachable-code

So, why is it that there is unreachable code detected in this code:

```
      public bool GetKeyPressed(KeyCode key)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
            if (keys[i].key == key && keys[i].pressed)
                return true;
            else
                return false;

        return false;
    }
```

The index (i) is apparently unreachable ... why?

Comment: If your `keys` contains more than 1 key, it will return after the first iteration, and never find your desired key inside. Try removing the else in your for loop, e.g. `for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
            if (keys[i].key == key && keys[i].pressed)
                return true;` only.

Comment: Just side note, why do you need loop if you are evaluating only first value? control will be returned to caller after first evaluation irrespective of key match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has a loop that evaluates once, therefore the first iteration will *always* return.

If that's what you want, just say that,

```
return keys[0].key == key && keys[0].pressed;
```

If however (which is what I suspect here), you want to return true if *any* in the array meets your test, then use LINQ's `Any()`,

```
return keys.Any(k => k.key == key && k.pressed);
```

Comment: holy cow, LINQ is beautiful. So... Just so I know what I'm doing here. The 'Any' is searching for 'Any' item in the list that contains the key I'm searching for and also makes sure it is pressed...?

Comment: Basically - `enumerable.Any(condition)` is true if any elements meet the condition passed in.

Answer (score 1):

Your code having two code path, one is through `if` condition and another is through the `else`. Which means the control will leave the function in these two ways. So the return statement after else will never triggers. That is why the compiler points it as unreachable code. This can be avoided by using the following code.

```
public bool GetKeyPressed(KeyCode key)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
        if (keys[i].key == key && keys[i].pressed)
            return true;          
        return false;
}
```

Comment: "let me add some explanations;" --- why not add them first then post?

Comment: @zerkms : I'm seeing that experts in this site, will add some key points initially and edit the post with complete explanations; just following the leaders. And some peoples will hit down for not explaining, but they wont remove the down after the edit, that's why I have added that quote.

Comment: @zerkms sometimes you've to kick off things first to win the race :-)

Comment: I probably would've gone for this approach if I wasn't shown the LINQ alternative. But thank you anyways :).

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on **jdphenix** answer, I think we need to understand *why* your loop "*evaluates once*" and only then can we understand why there is *"unreachable code"*.

```
public bool GetKeyPressed(Keys key)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
        if (keys[i].key == key && keys[i].pressed)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    return false;
}
```

The `for` loop has a single `if-else` statement that makes up the body.  The `if` guard if satisfied returns `true` otherwise it executes the next `else` statement which returns `false`.  The net result is that at most a single cycle of the loop will be executed before control is returned to the calling method irrespective of the number of items in `keys`.

It's more obvious if we look at the code via JetBrains *Resharper*:

[image]

The code may as well be written as:

```
public bool GetKeyPressed(Keys key)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; ) // Look Ma, no i++  !!!
        if (keys[i].key == key && keys[i].pressed)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    return false;
}
```

Don't make the mistake of thinking that the very last `return false` at the end of the method is not required because it is during the scenario where `keys.Count == 0`

[image]

Of course, formatting the code a bit more nicely goes a long way into revealing the problem that the first `return false` is redundant and could be simplified as per [un-lucky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39158136/585968):

[image]